# Get Access_Token of Cloud Firestore with Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, powerquery

I'm currently doing a Power Query to get data from the Cloud Firestore of Firebase. I'm not able to get the access token of the Cloud Firestore. I have my client id, client secret and the token URL.

The query I'm doing is

```
EncodedCredentials = "Basic "& Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(client_id & ":" & client_secret), BinaryEncoding.Base64),

Token_Response = Web.Contents(token_uri,
[
    Headers=[#"Authorization"=EncodedCredentials, #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"],
    //Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
    Content=Text.ToBinary("grant_type=client_credentials")
]
)
token_json = Json.Document(Token_Response),
token = token_json[access_token],
```

I get the error : DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' (400): Bad Request

Is there a specific URL to use? I'm using the same URL I have in my JS script to get the access token for the database.

I did a lot of research and I didn't find an answer with Cloud Firestore, only with Realtime DB of Firebase.

Thank you